# Create dynamic Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, func, c#-7.0

I don’t know if this is possible or not but I’m trying to refactor my code logic by doing the following;

I have a method called: `ApproveProcess<T1, T2>(T1 classObject, T2 classSecondObject) where T : class`

`T` is the generic object that I’m passing to the `ApproveProcess` method.
I have then the following method:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetById(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition, Func<IQueryable<T>)
{
           IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Where(condition);
           return query;
}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
Expression<Func<T1, bool>> expr2 = z => z.GetType().GetProperty("StringNumber").ToString() == "IB56";
BaseRepository<T1> iBase = new BaseRepository<T>(_databaseContext);
var tester1 = iBase. GetById(expr2, null).ToList();
```

I am trying to dynamically create the expression function based on the generic T object to then returns results.

I am not getting anyway.  If I change

```
`Expression<Func<T1, bool>> expr2'
```

to

```
Expression<Func<actualObject, bool>> expr2
```

I then get the following error

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

Is anyone able to tell me if what I am trying to do is actually possible? 
Any pointers to point me in the right direction would be grateful / Help?

Code Sample below;

```
_uowAdmin.AdminRepository.ApproveProcess<MeetingOne, MeetingRoomOne, MeetingRoomTwo>(new MeetingRoomOne(), new MeetingRoomTwo());
_uowAdmin.AdminRepository.ApproveProcess<DiningOne, DiningRoomOne, DiningRoomTwo>(new DiningRoomOne(), new DiningRoomTwo());


public void ApproveProcess<T, T1, T2>(T1 classObject, T2 classSecondObject) where T : class
{

    BaseRepository<T> iBase = new BaseRepository<T>(_databaseContext);
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2 = z => z.GetType().GetProperty("StringNumber").ToString() == "IB56";
    var tester1 = iBase.GetById(expr2, null).ToList();
}

public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{

    public IQueryable<T> GetById(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition, Func<IQueryable<T>)
    {
           IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Where(condition);
           return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the compilation errors in the code examples?

Comment: I have tried several ways to get it to work. I just not sure it is possible of what I am trying to do. I can't pass a dynamic expression func to the generic expression func to then return the results

Comment: I could create 20 plus similar methods that would return the results but wanting to create a more generic approach

Comment: Can you give an example (with compilable code) of one of those 20 plus methods?

Comment: Where is `T` in the declaration of `ApproveProcess`?

Comment: Code Sample added to main thread as 'Code Sample below'
@PauloMorgado

Comment: And still, there's no way it will ever compile.

Comment: If you're assuming every entity has a `StringNumber` property, why doesn't every entity derive from a base class with a `StringNumber` property?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "z");
var expr2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(parameter, "StringNumber"),
        Expression.Constant("IB56")),
    parameter);
```

Comment: Paulo Morgado That works well and returns what i need. Which is good.  However i need to re-think the type of design to achieve what i require though.